# Convert class from C++ to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, class

I'm trying to convert a C++ project to Delphi, but I don't know how to convert these two classes:

```
class CData;
class CContext;

class CData
{
public:
    CContext* Data;
};

class CContext
{
public:
    char Unk[2240];
    DWORD data1;
    DWORD data2;
    DWORD data3;
};
```

Usage:

```
CData* Data = (CData*)(0x00112233);

//This code obtain the bytes in memory of the address "0x00112233" based on the sizes specified at CContext class
```

Please, if someone knows, help-me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class is just a simple compound structure. That's a record in Delphi:

```
type
  TData = record
    unk: array [0..2240-1] of AnsiChar;
    data1, data2, data3: DWORD;
  end;
```

Your context type is just a pointer to that:

```
type
  TContext =^TData;
```

In the C   code this pointer is wrapped in a class which seems a little pointless to me.

Declare a variable that is a pointer to TContext:

```
var
  context: ^TContext;
```

Assign it like this:

```
context := Pointer($00112233);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `CContext` class is nothing more than a 2240 length string with 3 double-words of reserved space (likely that is never used).  `CData` is nothing more than a pointer to an instance of `CContext`.  To be more specific about how to port these, you would need to give more specifics on how they are used.  As it stands right now, you could likely just implement a version of `CData` that has a string member.

Comment: #Zac Howland, I've edited the question addind the usage of the class

Comment: @paulohr David pretty much answered the question, but what I was talking about was if those DWORD's are ever set.  If they are not used, then they are just reserved space, which you will likely not need to use in Delphi.  You could just have the text record.